# Is Trigger scheduled to fire at a specific time?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How can we know if a trigger is scheduled to fire at a specific time? i searched through all the apis but couldnt find. The closest api I found is getNextFireTime() and getFireTimeAfter(Date afterTime). My requirement is to find that if a trigger is scheduled to fire at a specific time.. If not schedule it to fire at that time.

Comment: Can somebody please answer this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Quartz [TriggerUtils](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html) utility methods.

The method `computeFireTimes(org.quartz.spi.OperableTrigger trigg, Calendar cal, int numTimes)` returns a list of Dates that are the next fire times of a Trigger.

The method `computeFireTimesBetween(org.quartz.spi.OperableTrigger trigg, Calendar cal, java.util.Date from, java.util.Date to)` returns a list of Dates that are the next fire times of a Trigger that fall within the given date range.

I hope this helps.